# undefined local variable or method `has_paper_trail'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

i am having some trouble with paper_trail gem. I love using it and it has nice features. It works fine when i run my server in development and test environments, but displays "**undefined local variable or method `has_paper_trail'** " error when i start to run the server in production environment. I couldn't be able to figure it out. help please?

Comment: can you provide some code about it? in particular, are there any initializers involved?

Comment: Thanks for your concern but its already solved as i posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanx vinod, your answer was helpful, but i just solved it by adding production as follows in /config/application.rb

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test production)))
```

it works fine.

Comment: Have you checked your Gemfile? Maybe you are requiring paper_trail only on development environment. Try not to play with this or it could affect other stuffs and mess with your environments.

Answer (score 3):

Check configuration :

If you defined in /config/application.rb like

> Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))

Change to :

> Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)